# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am trying to run `php artisan migrate` on a new database I just created. I was having many troubles with connecting to mariadb but I managed to fix it. Now whenever i try to connect to it, for some reason I can type no password or literally any password and i still connect to it. I don't know if that's normal. Anyway, i modified the `.env` file in my laravel project to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=liberty_comerce
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

But i get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = liberty_comerce and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`. If I change `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost` i get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = liberty_comerce and table_name = migrations and table_type  = 'BASE TABLE')`.

I tried running

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

every time i changed anything. I've been looking for answer online but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I was able to fix these errors via restarting the mariadb service and now I'm getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = liberty_comerce and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')` I tried different solutions that i found online but none of them worked for me. And I can still connect to mariadb via `sudo mariadb` or `sudo mariadb -u root -p` and then whatever the password that i type is, it works

Comment: Ok i found that the problem comes from the fact that the only way to connect to my mariadb via root is to use `sudo` but laravel can't use it.

Comment: Please create new database user then you can proceed it .

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused comes when **.env** DB_PORT doesn't match with your local db port. so first check the port and
then clear cache commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

and then do
`php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yet to get to the solution to it, I have tried couple of things like changing `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`, and:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```